# asp.net mvc route to a div on view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a link to a specific div on a view.

I was thinking something along these lines

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("#about", "Home") %> > </a>
```

or

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("~/Views/Home/About.ajax/#about")%> >
```

I know this isn't right. How can I create a link to a div or specific tag on the destination view, in the style of `<a name="someTagName"></a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `#about` right after the closing `%>`.

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("~/Views/Home/About.ajax/")%>#about">Your link text</a>
```

Take a look at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink).