# moving to page section through URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink

I am trying:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Link Label", "Index", "controller_name", new { area = "AreaName" }, new { @id = "documentation" })%>
```

To create the appropriate html to send the user to the "documentation" part of the web page by rendering the id into the title (i.e. ) and then dropping the "#documentation" onto the end of the url like so:

```
http://localhost/AreaName/controller_name/#documentation
```

when I type the url by hand the mvc routing sends the browser to the section ok, all I need is a way to make the Actionlink render the html correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution, already solved:

[Including an anchor tag in an ASP.NET MVC Html.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink)