# What are and how to use '#' in URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, razor

In my application I have a layout page for viewing the project:

This page have 4 sub-pages (Details, Photos, addresses and comments).

**Example:**

`/myproject` = Open the details page

`/myproject/Photos` = Open the Photos page

`/myproject/Addresses` = Opens the page addresses

`/myproject/Comments` = Open the page of comments

### Question

How to use `#` to load pages via ajax to the URL?

**Example**

`/myproject` = Open the details page

`/myproject#Photos` = Open the Photos page

`/myproject#Addresses` = Opens the page addresses

`/myproject#Comments` = Open the page of comments

In page layout where I have four buttons, click on the photo for example, the page would be loaded via ajax. and url go

from `/myproject`

to `/myproject#Photos`

### Resume

How to use '#' in asp.net MVC?

Comment: Looking at your comments in the answers, are you attempting to create links that have the hash tag in it e.g. `myproject#Photos` and you want them to simply scroll to the that section in the currently loaded page?

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if that is not clear enough.

Comment: See also this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are generally called URL fragments and are used as bookmarks on a page to navigate to different sections of that page.  When clicked they will scroll down the currently loaded page to the matching tag name.  I would recommend against using them  as paths to different pages.

You can use them as bookmarks by specifying the `fragment` in the Htmlhelper:

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Photos", "Action", "Controller", null, null, "Photos", null, null)
```

Then in your Photos partial  that represents the Photos sub-page, set the html *id* attribute to "Photos" in the div or label or whatever represents the beginning of the Photos partial.  The link created with the `@Html.ActionLink` will look for a html element ID that matches the word you typed into the fragment.

See [LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I do not need to do anything else, just the fact that the ID match the fragment (or hash) the scroll will be done?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, brain fart there... You need everything client side...

I'd use the following jQuery plug-in to parse the URL fragment:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-urlinternal-plugin/

and then call MyDiv.Load('yourcontenthere') to load the content you'd like into the desired DIV.

Comment: Wrong on both counts.  He's referring to pre-HTML5 AJAX history, and you can't do it with routing.

Comment: Exactly @SLaks! There are four pages that are loaded via ajax. What I need is a way to load the contents via ajax inside the div, and indicate in the url with # (hash, did not know the name of this feature) what content is being displayed.