# Removing pound/number '#' sign from URL

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-rewriting, isapi

I have strange issue, some my ASP.NET webpage's URL contain '#' sign (pound/number sign).

What is this sign? and how do i get rid of it. I don't need this to appear in my URL and it seems I can't control it.

I have tried Google ... most of the people are asking how to read query strings/data that appear after this sign ... but my question is, that I don't need to see this sign or any extra special characters in my URL.

Please help, and if possible, briefly explain the reason why this sign appears.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Could we see and example of a URL with it in?

Comment: Does it appear on page load? Or is it happening after you are clicking a "javascript link"?

Comment: http://localhost/myapplicationname/#.TxlHmIHAOy4

Comment: it appears on page load ... as soon as i hit F5/Ctrl+F5

Comment: @user402186 - are the pages getting loaded with the URL's  without the '#' sign ?

Comment: yup they do, but then the sign and the number after it automatically appear on the page load ...  for e.g. if type  
localhost/myapplicationname it loads, and by the time it has loaded it has become  
localhost/myapplicationname/#.TxlHmIHAOy4

Comment: Can we see the URL rewrite rule?

Comment: I have seen AJAX enabled sites that use such hashed values to track the current state of the page and insert them into the browsers history, for example the ASP.NET `ScriptManager` does this if you use the `EnableHistory` property. Does this fit with your website at all?

Comment: are you asking about this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink