# Url.Action passing fragment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How does one pass an inline anchor using the UrlHelper in ASP.NET MVC?

For example, if I have a URL:

```
/Foo/Bar/Information/FAQ#toc
```

And I was using the following Url.Action to get everything except the #toc fragment

```
<a class="next" href='@Url.Action("Bar", "Foo", new { subPath = "Information/FAQ" } )'>My Link Text</a>
```

**My question:** is there an overload for Url.Action to pass in the **#toc** fragment? I'd rather not use some hardcoded concatenation or @Url.Content (admittedly the way I cheat most of the time).

Comment: There are a couple solutions here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink

Comment: Not 100% certain but it seems like Url.Action does not have an overload but the canonical solution is to instead use Html.ActionLink eh? Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 0):

Use Html.ActionLink from LinkExtensions passing the "toc" to the fragment parameter:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
@Url.Action("view", "application", new { id = item.ApplicationId }, null, null, "Optt01")
```

Will take you to `/application/view/fc0fc182-d4e4-4b65-9d03-10be74c20212#Optt01`