# Linking to a particular (hidden) tab from the current page and other pages using anchors in MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a link which will go to some page but focus down automatically in mvc4.

@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") Like I m using html helpers in mvc it will take to the view of about but how will it move to the about and div or link there with the id of tips or something else.

Like in html we achieve this by doing this..

[Visit the Useful Tips](http://www.mydomain.com/aboutus.html#tips) (On home page)
Tips. (on about page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "Action", "Controller", null, null, "Anchor", null, null)
```

Here is another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink) about it

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) Now can I ask you one more thing? How to do active or current link class in mvc4. with these action links. Like I want the current page to be highlighted. my class name is selected but I don't know how will it work in a master page.

Comment: You should create a new question for that, you'll get help faster this way. And don't forget to mark the answer as a solution if it helped you ! ;)

Comment: Yes your answer helped me a lot :) but unfortunately i m new to this forum so couldn't vote here but I will say this is really workable :)

Comment: You can't vote up, but you can mark the answer as a solution.