# Include anchor tag in ASP.NET MVC 5 ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searched the web for an answer and tried Brad Wilson's suggested solution here:
[Including an anchor tag in an ASP.NET MVC Html.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink)

However, this does not work for me.

Here's what I did:

In Controller/Details/_PartialView file I place an anchor tag:

```
<a name="anchor-point"></a>
```

The _PartialView file is obviously rendered when Controller/Details is rendered.

In Controller/Index I have an ActionLink as follows

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Details", "Controller", null, null, "anchor-point", new { item => item.ID }, null)</td>
```

When I inspect the rendered HTML in Chrome the above link is not what I would, which is:

```
../Controller/Details/id#anchor-point
```

Have I misunderstood something or has usage changed since the original post. I am using MVC 5 ASP.NET 4.5.

Regards
Craig

Comment: I understand that you expect `../Controller/Details/id#anchor-point`, what is the rendered HTML like with the above `@Html.ActionLink` syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're telling the browser to scroll to an element with an **ID** of `anchor-point`, yet your element you posted you have only set the **name** attribute. Try this:

```
<a id="anchor-point"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that ID is the correct syntax, but why would it work with <a name ="..."> when I enter .../Controller/Index/id#anchor-point in to the browser manually ?  Anyway, I made the change and the URL in Chrome still shows as <a href="/Controller/Details/11">ID</a>. There's no #anchor after it still.

Comment: Don't you need to add it as a route value? @CraigRoberts

Comment: I will have a look at it thanks, but I've not yet added my own route map into config.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example ASP.NET MVC 5 ActionLink to Home controller, Index view with anchor tag "whatis"

```
 @Html.ActionLink(" What Is", "Index", "Home", null, null, "whatis", null, new { @class = "iconwhatis" });
```

With out the icon it would be

```
@Html.ActionLink(" What Is", "Index", "Home", null, null, "whatis", null, null);
```

Here's [a link](http://techo.luefher.com/coding/dot-net/mvc/microsoft-net-mvc-framework-how-to-use-named-anchors-url-hash-links-in-html-actionlink/) to a blog that explains it all very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
     <li>                                   
     <a href='@Url.Action("Login",new{id=item.id})'>@item.post_name</a>
      </li>
       }
  </ul>
```

Comment: Html anchor tag can be used in place of  @Html.ActionLink like above.