# How to incorporate href to section with Html.ActionLink in MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and have encountered a problem. I have an HTML page that scrolls down to a section when that section's name is clicked from the navigation bar but now I have to change this HTML line of code to MVC:

```
<li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
```

I have tried to use Html.ActionLink but have not had any success yet!

What I have so far:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Home", new { area = "#services" }, new { @class = "page-scroll" })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including an anchor tag in an asp.net mvc Html.ActionLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink)

Answer (score 3):

Create your own helper or use raw html

`<li><a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")#services">Link Text</a></li>`

OR

`<%= Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Controller", null, null, "services", new { parameter = "example"}, null) %>`

On your Index page:

`<div id="services">
    <p>Here is the content you want to make show when you click the link</p>
</div>`

When you click on 'Link Text' it will direct you to the services section of your Index page.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Home#services", new { @class = "page-scroll" })
```