# Change href based on requested view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out how i can change links on a _layout.cshtml based on the requested view.

When I am on the Home/Index I want the href to be '#Unhealthy' but when im on any other page, I want it to redirect back to the home page '/Home/Index/#Unhealthy'

**When on other page**

```
<li>
  <a href="/Home/Index/#Unhealthy"><i class="fa fa-warning warning"></i></a>
</li>
```

**When on Home/Index**

```
<li>
  <a href="#Unhealthy"><i class="fa fa-warning warning"></i></a>
</li>
```

How can I determine the requested view to swap this value?

*Note: I suppose if I cant do it at the server I can always change the values with javascript/jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use razor if your using MVC note i did this answer because you tagged MVC. If you are doing a MVC application this is by far the best way it can be done, no need for any javascript.

```
@if (window.location.pathname == "/"){
<li>
  <a href="#Unhealthy"><i class="fa fa-warning warning"></i></a>
</li>
}
else{
<li>
  <a href="/Home/Index/#Unhealthy"><i class="fa fa-warning warning"></i></a>
</li>
}
```

if you did want to do it the jQuery way this would work:

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
  if (window.location.pathname == "/"){ 
   $("#Link").prop("href", "#Unhealthy")
  }
  else {
    $("#Link").prop("href", "/Home/Index/#Unhealthy")
  }
});
```

html:

```
<li>
  <a id="Link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-warning warning"></i></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
    var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();
    var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower();
}

<li><a href="@(controller == "home" && action == "index" ? "#Unhealthy" : "/Home/Index/#Unhealthy")"><i class="fa fa-warning warning"></i></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Josh Stevens should work using MVC razor code but you could use same code on each page using @Html.ActionLink overloads

A quick search finds [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink) that is old syntax but concept correct

Without Testing try

@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Index", "Home", null, null, "Unhealthy", null, null)