# Append string in URL MVC form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am using hash to open mybootstrap modal. When I type `Home/Index#mymodal` in the URL manually , it works. The modal is displayed automatically. The problem is when I want to submit the form. Below is my code. I try to direct the form to `Home/Index#mymmodal`. But the URL shows `Home/Index%23mymmodal?inputName=john`. When I try to change the URL manually `Home/Index?inputName=john#mymmodal`, it works. So I try to append the `#mymmodal` at the  end of the current the URL. I used this but it does not work.

```
$('.ajaxLink').click(function (e) {
  location.hash = this.id; // get the clicked link id
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel navigation

  // get content with Ajax...
});
```

This is my code:

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index#mymodal", "Home")">
    <input type="text" name="inputName" Class="form-control">
</form>

<Button type="submit" value="search">Search</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in the UrlHelper maps to the action for which you're generating a link. You'll never have a method on your controller named `Foo#Something` - that's not a valid identifier in C#, VB.NET, etc.

If you want a hash appended to the URL, add it after the helper:

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")#mymodal">
    <input type="text" name="inputName" Class="form-control">
</form>
```

The hash isn't included in the HTTP request to the server, though, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: you are great! Thanks!

Comment: How if i want to insert in the @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", "Home", New With {.inputName = Item.Name}) ?

Comment: I assume you meant "how do I do the same thing with the HtmlHelper"? Meaning, how do you add a hash to generated hyperlink?

Comment: If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274586/including-an-anchor-tag-in-an-asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink